# Diagnosing Motherboard/CPU/ (most likely) GPU

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, gpu, diagnostic

OK, so I am trying to salvage my Mum's old PC for which she had bought a new power supply. After that it worked for a long time. After that time, it wouldn't boot (fans would come on very loud, power button LED would come on, disk drives would respond to the eject button etc. but no display, and the HDD LED wasn't flashing (wasn't booting properly).

About a week ago I though I'd try and salvage this poor PC. I tried to turn it on and got the same thing as mentioned above. I messed around trying different RAM configurations (swapping, single stick etc.), reseating the CPU, but to no avail. Until I took off the clip-on/clamp heatsink for the onbaord NVIDIA GeForce 7050 (part of a chipset on my motherboard; nForce 610i). I then turned on the power and attempted to boot, but to no avail.

However, the weird thing is, is that EVERY time I would do this (let the GPU overheat, though not to a dangerous level) and then reattach the heatsink to it again, this would allow me to boot, log in, transfer files, any task.

However, when it does come on and boot, and I am in Windows (windows 7) the whole PC OS/Mouse/Keyboard etc. will freeze occasionally and at pretty arbitrary times, requiring me to hard-reset it (hold the power button until the PC powers off itself).

To summerize my very bad question:

- Is it my graphics card that is failing
- Why would it work when I let it overheat (remove the heatsink and turn it on, though it won't boot during this unless I'd done prior
  that day for example)
- Can I salvage this PC by purchasing a new dedicated graphics card, or since it is part of the nForce 610i chipset, does that mean that I
  can't

Thank you for reading my badly put question. I am eager to hear good resposes, especially to the last point

Comment: It might be worth the $25 it would take to have a dedecated graphics card.  If all you care about are the files there are easier ways to get the files.

Comment: I have already retrieved my Mum's files. I just want to use the PC as a replacement for my laptop, as the Intel Q6600 is better (lightning fast for me). I know of no decent graphics card under about £50-60. If you're talking about just to diagnose idk, that's a waste of money if it isn't. Is there some software way to diagnose this.

Comment: Can you not check the hardware from within windows? such as running dxdiag?

Comment: I was able to find a low-profile GeForce 8300GS for under $25 USD on Amazon.  The board I mention is better then the onboard GPU.

Comment: But I want to diagnose if it is it and not the whole chipset, for example, so then I can buy a higher-end graphics card, and not waste money, I am on a tight budget.

Comment: You have already confirmed its a hardware problem.  There is no way to confirm its the onboad GPU unless you try a dedecated GPU.

Comment: I had my eye on the Asus AMD Radeon HD 7770 DirectCU Graphics Card (1GB, GDDR5, PCI Express 3.0 for £85 on Amazon. (Sapphire Vapor-X Radeon HD 7770, actually)

Comment: I know but my question was: If I bough a dedicated card, would that override the onboard one or just go through it or what?

Comment: I have bought a new graphics card. I will let you know if that has helped when it arrives.

Comment: OK so I installed a new graphics card (NVIDIA GeForce GT 640) and all worked well for a few days... until. I turn it on this morning and it doesn't P.O.S.T. Until I let the _onboard_ NVIDIA chip overheat and reinsert the heatsink. What is happening? Very unreliable. Is there any way to fixthis appart from buying a new motherboard (and if I did, would my power supply still have enough plugs (5V, 12V etc.) to plug into the newer (non OEM) board? And if possible, does anyone know a good website where I could buy a new mobo with an Intel LGA775 socket, DDR3 and some USB 3.0?

Comment: Even better, is there a way to completely disable that chipset (I don't know what that is - if it's too integral). The chipset is nForce 610i with graphics chip Nvidia GeForce 7050. Would thatbe possbile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every since installing the new graphics card for a while (ever since my last comment), my computer has worked fine, thanks for your responses.

If anyone else has had this problem,Isuggest you at least try one of these cards (very cheap, and plays Skyrim on Ultra :D).